# How do I deploy applets(class files) in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, deployment, applet

my project has 2 JSwing applets(no main class).

working: thing is *they have to be together* as they both work upon the same database. **one stores, the other reads and process.**

problem: in netbeans i used build and clean& build option but they seem to generate only .jar file and no .class file in "dist" folder.

situation:i want to embed these 2 applets separately on different html pages.
how do i achieve this?

Comment: *"no .class file in "dist" folder."* Loose class files can no longer be deployed. Classes **have to be** in a digitally signed Jar.

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem**
>   In Netbeans i used build and clean& build option but they seem to
>   generate only .jar file and no .class file in "dist" folder.

JAR file itself is called **Java Archive**. It is nothing but a bundle of class files.

You can get your `.class` files by using any archive utility like [winzip](http://www.winzip.com/win/en/downwz.html), [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) etc...

Just right click on your .jar file > open with winzip/7zip > and drag and drop the contents inside it to your preferred directory.

Comment: it has several .class files. how do i use them with a HTML page? https://imgur.com/a/4AEiA

Comment: In your HTML file, you can use it as `<applet code="PrefApp.class" width="40" height="30">
</applet>`

Comment: i tried didn't worked :( displays nothing.
is there a way i create a main() in a class and call the applets sequentially?

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: i extracted the .class files and used them accordingly.

Comment: have you ever created an applet before without using an IDE?

Comment: no. its first time i made one. due to time limits i used drag and drop method in netbeans.
i made two applets. one saves some data to the database(jdbc used), the other applet reads from the data saved and processes it.
then i self-signed the project in netbeans and hit "clean and build".it generated a "dist" folder and it has following: "the .jar file contains no .class file " see here:https://imgur.com/a/I75tc 
these are the files generated

Comment: It's pretty simple straight forward process. First make a `Hello World` application without using any IDE. Applet classes are simply called from html files. Learn this and you'll definitely figure out how to solve it. Ping me if you face any issues.

Comment: *"..due to time limits.."* Seems you left this homework to the last minute, and what you really need is to develop better time management skills.. Note that ***deploying*** a relatively simple applet is harder than writing and debugging it in an IDE in the first place!